# add image as base64 in ckEditor in angular 5

Tags: angular, base64, ckeditor, angular5

1. i want to add ckEditor in my angular project
2. i want to browse image & want to display it in **base64**, while i sent it at that time i want all those content in HTML format & image in base64.
3. i am using **ngx-ckeditor: ^0.4.0** in **ANGULAR 5**
4. below is my code, add JS in my index.html file

   ```
   <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
   ```
5. import in my Module

   ```
   import { CKEditorModule } from 'ngx-ckeditor';
   ```
6. add tag in my HTML file

   ```
   <ckeditor name="html_template" [(ngModel)]="html_template"></ckeditor>
   ```

> ho can i browse image in base64 format?